Why does an infinitesimal slit act as an isotropic light source
For a finite slit, the expression for irradiance is as follows,
$$I=I_0\operatorname{sinc}^2\beta$$
where
\begin{array}{ccc}I_0=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{bE_r}{r_0}\right)^2&\text{and}&\beta=\frac{kb}{2}\sin\theta.\end{array}
as the width $b$ is getting infinitesimally smaller, $\beta$ is approaching 0 and the sinc function approaches 1, but $I_0$ is also approaching 0. So how can the irradiance be equal to $I_0$?

The image of the intensity equation suggests $c$ is a constant (it's italicized vs the upright $\sin$ term)) and not the function $\operatorname{sinc}$ (which would be all upright). Can you clarify the intent?

IDK about an "infinitessimal" slit, but a hole whose width is about the same as the wavelengths of the waves impinging on it from one side emits spherical waves out the other side. This video explains: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqTWSSBcV_4 It's kind of long, but it's the best I could find after a brief search. The punch line is delivered about ten minutes in. For a deeper explanation, you can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle

my apologies due to formatting the sinc function is written as sin.c^2 .I can confirm that its the sinc function squared

$I_0$ is supposed to be the intensity at the central maximum, so I would think it should be independent of $b$. Can you also attach the diagram of the single slit from your textbook? It might be useful to see how the original source defines everything.
